# How to subtract two times from two datetime and calculate is elapse time from 61 seconds or not?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm working on an asp.net core MVC project. This project about identifying online and offline users, I have two datetime, one of the stores in a database, and another is current datetime, and I must know that time stored in a database elapsed from 61 seconds or not?

I  subtract two Datetime and finally use TotalSeconds property.but my output is -22095 or 2319208 and so on.

```
   public void CheckUserStatus()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var userTime = _context.Sessions.Where(x => x.LastOnline).Select(x => new {x.LastConnectTime, x.Id});

        foreach (var time in userTime)
        {
            TimeSpan diffrence = now.Subtract(time.LastConnectTime);
            int mytime = Convert.ToInt32(diffrence.TotalSeconds);

            if ( mytime < 61)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(time.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect out of time base on seconds, for example, right now my output is -22095 or 2319208, and so on but I don't know 2319208 is a regular time or not?

Comment: is the time store in database also UTC? It would be more help if you can provide sample datetime in your question

Comment: @unmang, I store in database base on DateTime.Now.

Comment: that's a problem that you are comparing with UTC Now .Or convert `LastConnectTime` to UTC time. Suggest you use DateTimeOffset in database.

Comment: @umang,this is a format that I store in database as a DateTime.Now 2019-06-09 12:17:00.7656606

Comment: Do you have to use `DateTime.UtcNow`? can you use DateTime.Now

Comment: @umang, right now in my code I'm using DateTime.Now for storing DateTime in Database.

Comment: In the CheckUserData method it is using UtcNow? Can that be change to `DateTime.Now` ?

Comment: @umang, yeah I changed UtcNow to Datetime.Now

Comment: How has result changed now?

Comment: @Umang, I don't know how to calculate time is elapsed from 61 seconds or not?

Comment: What does this part of your sentence really mean: "time is elapsed from 61 seconds or not"? I can read the words, I just don't understand what you want to do here.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, I mean I have two datetime one of them store in a database, and another datetime is current datetime I want to subtract two datetime, and I find out how much seconds passed from 61 seconds?

Comment: passed *from* 61 seconds, you mean "over" 61 seconds? So for instance, if the two datetime values had 63 seconds between them, you want the value 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check that like this :

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan past = now - now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
TimeSpan post = now - now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(61));

Console.WriteLine(now);

// Should be False: Passed time is less than 60 seconds
Console.WriteLine(past.TotalSeconds > 60);

// Should be True: Passed time is more than 60 seconds
Console.WriteLine(post.TotalSeconds > 60);
```